AMPscript Current Sunday
I'm attempting to build a call by date and have that date be the Saturday of the given week. These emails are sent Monday - Friday, I'm struggling to lock down the AMPscript for it. Here is what I have so far.
%%[
var @currentDate, @currentDayOfWeek, @daysUntilSaturday, @nextSaturday, @monthName, @day, @year 

SET @currentDate = NOW(1)
SET @currentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(@currentDate, "D")
SET @daysUntilSaturday = 7 - @currentDayOfWeek + 1
SET @nextSaturday = DATEADD(@currentDate, @daysUntilSaturday, "D")
SET @monthName = ProperCase(FormatDate(@nextSaturday, "MMMM"))
SET @day = DatePart(@nextSaturday, "D")
SET @year = DatePart(@nextSaturday, "Y")
]%%
%%=v(@monthName)=%% %%=v(@day)=%%, %%=v(@year)=%%


This was fun :)
%%[
Set @currentDate      = NOW(1)
Set @currentDayOfWeek = FormatDate(@currentDate,"ddddd")
If @currentDayOfWeek != "Saturday" Then
   For @i = 1 To 6 Do
      Set @loopThroughDays = DateAdd(@currentDate,@i,"D")
      Set @dayCheck        = FormatDate(@loopThroughDays,"ddddd")
      If @dayCheck == "Saturday" Then
         Set @monthName     = ProperCase(FormatDate(@loopThroughDays, "MMMM"))
         Set @day           = DatePart(@loopThroughDays, "D")
         Set @year          = DatePart(@loopThroughDays, "Y")
      Else EndIf
   Next @i
Else 
   Set @monthName = ProperCase(FormatDate(@currentDate, "MMMM"))
   Set @day       = DatePart(@currentDate, "D")
   Set @year      = DatePart(@currentDate, "Y")
EndIf
]%%

%%=v(@monthName)=%% %%=v(@day)=%%, %%=v(@year)=%%
%%[/*Output: April 06, 2024*/]%%


I would go for something similar to this since it is easy to understand. The downside of this is that the loop still goes through till the end, even though it is iterated with the right "Saturday". Kudo for both of the answers!

Agreed on the downside. I went in thinking assigning var i to 6 w/in the variable assignment block would address that, but that didn't work.

Here's how I'd do it -- with a little trick using indexOf and a string array of week days:
%%[

/*SET @currentDate = dateparse('2024-04-06')*/
set @currentDate = Now(1)

set @daysOfWeek = "SunMonTueWedThuFriSat"
set @dayOfWeekToFind = format(@currentDate,"ddd")
set @dayOfWeekNum = divide(add(indexof(@daysOfWeek,@dayOfWeekToFind),2),3)
SET @daysUntilSaturday = mod(Subtract(7,@dayOfWeekNum),7)

output(concat("<br>currentDate: ",@currentDate))
output(concat("<br>dayOfWeekNum: ",@dayOfWeekNum))
output(concat("<br>daysUntilSaturday: ",@daysUntilSaturday))

SET @nextSaturday = DATEADD(@currentDate, @daysUntilSaturday, "D")

]%%
<!-- more format patterns here: https://ampscript.guide/format -->
<br>%%=format(@nextSaturday,"D")=%%


Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/02ybBk34
